# How to sum the values of one column depending on the value of another?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

with LibreOffice Calc I'm trying to set something up so it sums the values of column D IF the corresponding row in column A contains certain words. So far I know sumif works, but how do I set it up so the criteria portion just looks for key words in the cells in A instead of the whole cell?

Thanks

Comment: okay, so i found out about wildcards, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working. my formula looks like **=SUMIF(E91:E101," * (1) * ",L91:L101)**, but it's returning 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so i fidgeted around and went into Tools->Options...->LibreOffice Calc->Calculate->"Enable regular expressions in formulas" and was able to use `=SUMIF(E91:E101, ".*(1).*", L91:L101)`!